# ASP.NET Can't dynamically add new controls to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, addition, dynamic-controls

I want to add some `FileUploads` to the page dynamically and control them it postback, because if to use plain html tags and not asp.net controls it may cause issues with the file upload.

I've defined in `ASPX` page the panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelViewer" BackColor="Azure" Width="400" Height="400" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

And in `<% %>` tags trying to add dynamically the correct count of file uploads forms.
The count of file upload forms depends on MySQL record in table, it could be different for the users.

I'm trying to add dynamically so, just for the start:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "click me!";
panelViewer.Controls.Add(btn);

FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
fileUpload.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
panelViewer.Controls.Add(fileUpload);
```

But no success, when I push `Ctrl + U` in HTML response from server, I've got:

```
<div id="panelViewer" style="background-color:Azure;height:400px;width:400px;">
</div>
```

There are no controls in HTML response, so in rendered page from server.

I've tried not to use earlier defined panel and make it dynamically added to the `runat form`, but again the same result.

How could I fix such a problem?
Thank you!

Comment: can you show us the error you are getting?

Comment: @oleg you should also set runat=server attribute of any asp.net control

Comment: @Devjosh at any??? )))

Comment: where did you added the code for adding button and file upload control?

Answer (score 0):

try to include `btn.ID` as property of your control.

Comment: does your panel under an `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
Style style = new Style();
style.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
fileUpload.ApplyStyle(style);
```